# Hypothesis Testing of endpoint of Uniform distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, likelihood-ratio

Let $c$ be a positive constant. Suppose I have $X$~$Unif(0,\theta)$ and I wish to test the null hypothesis $H_0: \theta \leq c$ against the alternative hypothesis $H_1:\theta > c$. Suppose I did a sample $X_1,...,X_n$ but I obsrerve them with perturbation - that is, I actually have on hand $Y_1:=X_1+\epsilon_1,...,Y_n:=X_n+\epsilon_n$ where $\epsilon_i$ are i.i.d. ~ $N(0,\sigma^2)$. How should I conduct a hypothesis testing?

**Idea:** I was thinking of using Likelihood ratio test, since that allows me to do hypothesis testing on a composite null hypothesis. I can take into account the errors in my likelihood function by convolving the uniform with the normal. However, when I want to define critical values, I have difficulty because I have no idea how to approximate the test statistic to any distribution and hence derive rejection regions.

**Idea 2:** Rao's score test, since here I know how to approximate the test statistic distribution for large sample size, but the only form of Rao's test I know involves point null hypothesis (i.e. testing $\theta = c$) - sadly, my bound $c$ is conservative upper bound, so there is a large chance that $\theta$ is smaller than $c$ and I dont want this case to be a rejection case.

Other ideas would also be appreciated.

Comment: For background see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103984/estimating-uniform-distribution-endpoints-using-data-with-errors/104013?noredirect=1#comment201005_104013

Comment: This is really a part of your earlier question  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103984/estimating-uniform-distribution-endpoints-using-data-with-errors    and should be asked there, with an edit/extension of that question!

Comment: I'm inclined to agree that this is rather close to the question @kjetil points to. Is this really a distinct question?